# Eclipse Can't find & install SDK platform Android 1.6 API 4

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget

I would like to install Android SDK platform **1.6** (API 4).

So, on **Eclipse**,  I went to **Android SDK and AVD Manager** tool, I click on "**Available packages**" and expand "**Android Repository**".

But I can not find Android 1.6 API 4, the minimum version it shows is v2.1 API 7.

why? How can I install android 1.6 API 4?

Answer (score 1):

In the repository view, it appears for me as 'SDK Platform Android 1.6' and 'Google APIs by Google Inc.', both version 4 (note: these are two different things that I won't explain here).

Things are clearer if you pick the 'API Level' radio button at the bottom of the SDK Manager. If this doesn't appear then your SDK tools are probably out of date and I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: The SDK Manager allows you to upgrade the Tools & Platform Tools. If you can't find this either (hard to comment on old versions) then you are best off starting again from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html  
For clarity, what I was referring to is this view, shown in the 'API Level' display mode: http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/android-sdk-manager.png

Answer (score 1):

1. Run as administrator
2. Uninstall any API greater than 1.X
3. Close SDK Manager
4. Reopen in administrator mode
5. Now u have all APIs in the list